# TemporaryFile is empty while script is running

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write into a temp file and use it in a subprocess.
But it seems that the temp file is empty while the script is still running.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
  
import subprocess
import tempfile

tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
tmp.write(bytes("testcontent", encoding = 'utf-8'))
tmp_path = tmp.name
output = subprocess.run('cat ' + tmp_path, shell=True, capture_output=True)
print(tmp.name)
print(output.stdout)


existing_file = "/tmp/testfile"
output = subprocess.run('cat ' + existing_file, shell=True, capture_output=True)
print(output.stdout)
```

And this is the output:

```
/tmp/tmpllexuy_q
b''
b'testcontent\n'
```

When the script is finished the temp file exists and the content I wrote is also in the file:

```
cat /tmp/tmpllexuy_q
testcontent
```

If I use an already existing file that I created manually and wrote some content in, the subprocess call does work and gets the content of the file.

So is there something I am doing wrong? Maybe in the tempfile declaration "tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)"?

Comment: It works for me if I add a `tmp.flush()` after the `tmp.write()` call.

Comment: thank you! this works for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `tmp.flush()` somewhere before the call to `subprocess.run()`, it will ensure that any buffered data there is be will actually be written the physical file. This worked for me when I tried it (after modifying it for Windows and successfully reproducing the problem).